# Why should AppDelegate be altered as little as possible?

Tags: iphone

In start of my IPhone development I used to have an ugly programing structure. Often I forgot to release memory I used to allocate, didn't follow coding conventions and believe me there are more. What I also did was not using **singleton** and instead putting the core data in **AppDelegate** till I later realized, this was not a good practice.
Now when I make follow all coding conventions and make use of **singleton**, I often wonder why we don't do the same in **Appdelegate**? All I know is that making minimal changes to your **AppDelegate** is a good practice, but not why.
Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggest **"AppDelegate"** , Let it to handle only the **application** related **delegate**, Although you could include as much code as you want in **"AppDelegate"** but won't be a good practice ..You could consider creating an separate class to handle your `coreData` and make it iVar of **"AppDelegate"**, So all your application files could easily access it through **"AppDelegate"**,

Comment: Now I do implement MVC in my applications. So is good practice perhaps the only reason?

Comment: @Nitish : It's good and very efficient to use MVC at **UI** level but at application level,it's required to use **design patten** .